# How to get outgoing HTTP requests after visiting a site?

Tags: web

Say I visit https://google.com, I find it makes several other HTTP calls that fetch data to render the Google homepage, including:

- https://www.google.com/complete/search?q&cp=0&client=gws-wiz&xssi=t&hl=en-HK&authuser=0&psi=EB5hYtyeKNaXr7wPuumHyAQ.1650531857155&dpr=2
- https://aa.google.com/u/0/_/gog/get?rt=j&sourceid=538
- etc

[image]

Is there a way to fetch these outgoing HTTP requests with server-side code? The function I am looking to implement is basically:

```py
def fetchOutgoingLinks(url):
    # TODO

fetchOutgoingLinks("https://google.com") == ["https://www.google.com/complete/search?q&cp=0&client=gws-wiz&xssi=t&hl=en-HK&authuser=0&psi=EB5hYtyeKNaXr7wPuumHyAQ.1650531857155&dpr=2", "https://aa.google.com/u/0/_/gog/get?rt=j&sourceid=538", ...]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you hoping to write a browser plugin to do this while you browse the web?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller hi, I am looking to implement fetchOutgoingLinks on the server-side. Therefore, browser plugin is not something I am looking to

Comment: Are you hoping to open a browser on the server then?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no i am not, but i want to simulate the browser behavior on the server-side